# Move the object in a specific area

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, drag-and-drop

I have a circle called `circle` and a line called `ground` in the View.

[image]

I can drag & move the circle in the whole view, but when I try to limit it (in the code) to move only under the ground area - it works (when I try to drag it above the ground) and the circle moves only by my x location dragging, BUT when I try to drag it back under the ground - the circle only moves by the x location dragging and the y location dragging doesn't change (the y is the ground y).

How can I make it move back again, in a free way, under the ground and not only by the x location of the dragging?
Here is what I tried so far:

```
let ground = SKSpriteNode()
    var circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

//        ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        ground.color = SKColor.redColor()
        ground.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 5)
        ground.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: self.frame.size.height / 5)

        self.addChild(ground)

        circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) ,CGRectGetMinY(ground.frame) - (circle.frame.size.height / 2))
        circle.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        circle.glowWidth = 1.0
        circle.fillColor = SKColor.orangeColor()

        self.addChild(circle)

    }
    var lastTouch: CGPoint? = nil
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
        if circle.position.y < ground.position.y - (circle.frame.size.height / 2){
           circle.position = touchLocation
        } else {
            circle.position.x = CGFloat(touchLocation.x)
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
        if circle.position.y < ground.position.y - (circle.frame.size.height / 2) {
            circle.position = touchLocation
        } else {
            circle.position.x = CGFloat(touchLocation.x)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it:

In `touchesMoved` func I wrote this code:

```
for touch in touches {
            if touchLocation.y < ground.position.y {
                circle.position = touchLocation
            } else {
                circle.position.x = touchLocation.x
            }
        }
```